# Problem with MouseEvent for 3d model on Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouseevent, 3d-model

I recently started experimenting with three.js, I'm trying to play a MouseEvent so that the 3D model moves its position slightly as if to follow the cursor, always remaining in the middle of the page.
With a little bit of code written by me it's a bit of a look around I came to a point where the 3d model follows the cursor but in an inverse way, in the sense that when I move the cursor to the left part of the wireframe, for example, the 3d model is move to the right. I also noticed that the closer I get to the corners of the wireframe the more the 3D model gets smaller, while I would like to make sure that it always remains at its original size.

In addition I would like to make sure that when I shrink the wireframe, moving to a size that is not desktop, the 3D model does not do any of this, remaining just in the middle of the page.

the code is as follows:

```js
var container, stats;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
init();
animate();
function init () {
container = document.createElement('div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 15;

//model

var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

loader.load("/models/skull.json",function ( obj ) {

var box = new
THREE.Box3().setFromObject( obj );
var center = new THREE.Vector3();
box.getCenter ( center );
obj.position.sub (center);
obj.rotation.y = Math.PI;
scene.add ( obj );
});

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
container.appendChild ( renderer.domElement );
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

window.addEventListener ('resize', onWindowResize, false );
}

function onWindowResize() { windowHalfX = window.innerWidth;
windowHalfY = window.innerHeight;
camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;
}

function animate () {
requestAnimationFrame ( animate );
render();
}

function render89 {
camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera-position.x ) * .01;
camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .01;
camera.lookAt ( scene.position );
renderer.render ( scene, camera );
}
```

In this image, for example, I had the cursor at the bottom right corner.

[image]

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it acceptable to use `THREE.OrbitControls()`?

Comment: Yes, of course is acceptable if iunderstand what you mean, I've actually already connected the THREE.OrbitControls() script. sorry if I did not specify it in the code.

Comment: Why do you want to use your own mouse logics, if you already use these controls?

Comment: I would like to adjust, for example I would like the 3d model to remain at its normal size wherever you move the cursor, but in this case, with this code the more I move away from the center of the wireframe the more it gets smaller. I don't understand how to fix it

Comment: https://codepen.io/interaktiv-ca/pen/XayZPx I would like to do something like this, but not with the jaw of the skull and the eye, just 3d model